# Forcing Scroll-Down on iOS (iPhone) causes Fixed element to disappear

Tags: ios, css, iphone, scroll

I am building a modal popup window for mobile.

I noticed that when I try to scroll below the limit of the modal (see "B" part, on "A" part I reached the bottom),
The fixed section I have on the bottom becomes covered with gray, the more I try to force scroll.

It's happening both on Safari and Chrome, See this photo:

[image]

This is the order and CSS of the elements:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.popup-r {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.fix-section {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: plz send the html code?

Comment: `<HTML><BODY><DIV Class="POPUP-R"><DIV Class="Fix-section"></div></div>`